# SQL Server SP with datetime parameter from jdbc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have a SP like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeProc](@AsOfDate datetime=null ,@client varchar(8000)=null)
```

when I execute it in SQL server management studio and pass like 28-Feb-2017 to the AsOfDate it returns data.

In jdbc land however no matter what I try it returns nothing. I am calling it as a preparedstatement like so

```
String sql = "{call dbo.SomeProc(?, ?)}";
ps = connection.prepareCall(sql);

// tried this
ps.setDate(1, <date object>)
// tried this
ps.setTimestamp(1, <timestamp object>)
// tried this
ps.setString(1, dd-MMM-yyyy)

ps.setString(2, clientName);
boolean result = ps.execute();
if(result == false) { // <- Its always false
    return null;
}
ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet();
```

Comment: After you `ps.execute()` does `ps.getUpdateCount()` return a value?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427224(v=sql.110).aspx